# JAVA:Not able to add multiple object in arraylist. The object information is getting override

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist

I have excel sheet with Test case data. Each test case might one contain single or multiple steps. I wanted to pull all data(3 fields) for each steps of test case into Arraylist "TestStepsList" by iterating through excel (by using for loop for each row). Once I check if new test case has started in excel I put all step data (Arraylist "TestSTepsList") into another array TestCaseList. So TestCaseList is a list of list.

TestCaseID  Input               Keyword
TC_01       Main Window1            Menuitem_Verification
TC_02       Configuration Manager-2_1   SubMenuitem_Verification-1
TC_02       Configuration Manager-2_2   SubMenuitem_Verification-2

Code is as follows:

```
    for(int j=0;j<Total_Row;j++){   



    int total_Steps_TestCase =(int) test_Case_Data.get(curr_TCID);
    List<String> TestStepsList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (flag_CreateNewTC == 1) // Checking if we are on first step of the test case and need to create new list(TestSTepList)

    {           

        TC_index = 1;
        l = 0;

        TestStepsList.add(0, curr_TCID);
        TestStepsList.add(1, Curr_TCInput);
        TestStepsList.add(2, Curr_TCKword);


        if(TC_index ==((int) test_Case_Data.get(curr_TCID))) //Checking if test case is only single line. In such case we will add that testcase object(list to 
                                     //TestCase List)                   
        {
            seq=seq-1;
            TestCaseList.add(seq,TestStepsList);
        }

    }

    else  //If a test case is multi step we will add all steps into TestSteplist till new test case begins
    {

        l=l+1;
        TestStepsList.add(curr_TCID);
        TestStepsList.add(Curr_TCInput);
        TestStepsList.add(Curr_TCKword);

        TC_index++;

        if(TC_index ==((int) test_Case_Data.get(curr_TCID)))//If this is last step of existing test case then we need to add entry to TestCaseList List

        {
            seq=seq-1;
            TestCaseList.add(seq, TestStepsList);
                    }

        }

    }

}
```

The problem I am facing is that for single line test case entry is properly getting added in TestCaselist, but for testccase with multiple steps only last row is getting added. For e.g if Testcase consist of 3 rows only last step is getting added

I think best practice is to initialize the list object everytime you add any item to the list but in my case its not possible as I wanted to add multiple steps in the same list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking the `seq=seq-1` might have something to do with it.  You keep pushing the `TestStepsList` into the same element in your `TestCastList`, if I'm reading your code correctly.

If you're adding to the end of the `List`, then leave out the index argument.  Otherwise, change your index argument to `seq-1` and stop reassigning `seq`.

```
TestCaseList.add(seq - 1, TestStepsList);
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> TestStepsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

keep this outside of your `for` loop.

because every time you are looping through it you are creating a new `ArrayList`.

Comment: I have done that initially but doing that only the last entry from the excel sheet is saved. It override all the entry. For e.g If I have entries TC01 (single step), TC02 (3 steps) then in case if declaration is done outside for loop then object only contain TC02 enteries. Right now the problem I am facing is that TC01 and TC02 are added to object but for TC02 only single row(step) is getting added. (The last row). The initial 2 rows are overriden.